# Como puedo crear un array multidimensional en mi codigo del juego Piedra Papel o Tijera?

Tags: python, array

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No te preocupes por lo que pueda faltar, solo necesito sabe como agregar un array multidimensional que imprima las veces que el jugador ha ganado, cuando la computadora gana y las veces que queda empate

Comment: Por favor, cuando incluyas código en la pregunta no lo hagas con imágenes. Las imágenes pueden dar problemas a algunos usuarios, y además obligan a quein te quiera ayudar a teclear todo el código para replicar el problema. Incluye siempre el código como texto, delimitado por una línea inicial con ``` y otra al final.

Answer (score 0):

Los arreglos multidimensionales en python se definen como un arreglo de arreglos

```
states = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

for i in states:
    for j in i:
        print(j, end=" ")
    print()

#resultado
#1 2 3 
#4 5 6 
#7 8 9
```

De esta manera creas una matriz de 3x3 y la imprimes con su correspondiente formato.

Aunque si solo quires contabilizar las veces que gana el humano, la maquina y los empates, recomiendo que solo hagas un arreglo de 3 posiciones `win = [0,0,0]` donde cada posición representa dichos estados.

Comment: Pero como pudiera hacerlo aqui? estoy muy confundido

Comment: @ManiOzuna Por ejemplo tienes dicho arreglo win = [0,0,0], si gana el jugador le sumas 1 a la posición 0 win[0] += 1, si gana la maquina le sumas uno a la primera posición win[1] += 1, y si es empate a la tercera posición win[2] += 1. Para saber cuantas veces a ganado cada quien vasta con acceder a las posiciones correspondientes.

Comment: Bueno, para ser técnicos, no son arreglos sino listas.

Comment: @revliscano en toda la razón, python no tiene arreglos como tal, pero es practico explicarlo así

Comment: @denso, he hablado con mi profesor y me dice que el arreglo multidimensional debe imprimir las perdidas, las victorias y los empates, me podrias ayudar a organizar esto en mi código?